# time range overlap by one php function and report

Tags: time, overlap, date-range

I need to write one php function that checks whether four different time ranges are overlapping and, in the case if some of them are, to put the notice in a browser that : 'range#1' intersects with 'range#2'. Any idea?Thx in advance.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the details on what have you tried so far? Please share a minimum working example

Comment: i attempted to follow this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609779/check-date-ranges-start-and-end-date-for-overlap

but i doubt it will work in my case. i suggest to solve my problem by using OOP maybe?